# regex_error(error_stack) C++

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio, c++11

I am having an issue where I get the `regex_error(error_stack)` when running my program. This only occurs sometimes (depending on the input string). I am using a comma separated split while respecting quotes:

My regex expression is:

```
",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))"
```

And here's the code:

```
void split( const std::string &s, std::vector<std::string> &elems, const std::string &rgx_str ) {
    std::regex rgx( rgx_str );

    std::sregex_token_iterator iter( s.begin(), s.end(), rgx, -1 );
    std::sregex_token_iterator end;

    while ( iter != end ) {
        std::string tmp = *iter;
        elems.push_back( trim( tmp ) );
        ++iter;
    }
}
```

The error occurs on the line where `iter(...)` is created (actually, error is buried deep in the regex code, but that's the last part of my code used). I am using MS Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. I have tested the regex expression on [regexr.com](http://regexr.com) and it works fine. The string it constantly fails on is below (it is a single line in a file):

```
"1942","96 Level Acc #2","",,,0,1,0,0,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,0,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,0,0,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,0,0,0,0,0,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,0,0,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,0,0,2.00000004008175e+021,0,0,2.00000004008175e+021,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2.00000004008175e+021,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2.00000004008175e+021,0,0,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,2.00000004008175e+021,0,2.00000004008175e+021,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"DEVELOPMENT","<ND>  ","<ND>","<AUTO>","<New>","<ND>","<ND>","<ND>","<ND>","<ND>","<ND>","<ND>","<Not defined>","<ND>","<ND>","<AUTO>","< New >","< ND >","4.5","<ND>","<ND>","<ND>","<M>","<In Schedule>","<Not defined>","<Not defined>","<LHD 9 (Manned)>","<Operating>","","96","00","00","","","96-0000-ST","9150 R/B (ORE)","","B4 96-9150 TRK","","","MDB5","","-","","","95 TO 96 COB #4 MINE","","0","0","0","0","0","0","96","","","",Fixed Duration,6.4dtm/w,0d,As Soon As Possible,,,,0,,0,,"<Project>",Latest,Combined,Task,1,0,"","",0,0mi,""
```

I cannot see any issues with the regex or the string I am trying to match. It just seems like the `sregex_token_iterator` fails. I have tried increasing the stack to 10MB, and it didn't help. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please, provide [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Atomic_alarm 
std::vector<string> data;
std::string commaSeperatedData = [above string which fails];
std::string COMMA_SEPARATION_RESPECTING_QUOTES = ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))";
split( commaSeperatedData, data, COMMA_SEPARATION_RESPECTING_QUOTES );

Comment: @Chris M - a "mcve" is a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"; please, read carefully the page pointed by Atomic_alarm

Answer (score 0):

For some reason there is a stack overflow, i am not sure why. I have tried to debug a little from the call stack but it fails at different stages. It is out of my scope to debug it in any time soon. May be someone can come with a better way to explain it.

Call stack is never ending, I have checked few cases where it is failing. But seems like it has nothing to do with the string or regex, instead the iterator parsing internally is going in to a huge loop(it may be because of the large string or may be some character parsing, kind of infinite loop) for some reason

Call Stack is full of these ::

```
regex1.exe!std::_Matcher<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > >,char,std::regex_traits<char>,std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > > >::_Match_pat(std::_Node_base * _Nx) Line 4756    C++
```

But below is a working solution ::

```
void split(const  std::string &s, std::vector<std::string> &elems, const std::string &rgx_str) {
    std::regex rgx(rgx_str);
    std::smatch mat;
    std::regex rgxx(",");
    string s1(s);

    while (std::regex_search(s1, mat, rgxx))
    {
        elems.push_back(mat.prefix());
        s1 = mat.suffix();
    }
}
```

Let me know if this solves your issue?

Comment: Negative. In your example, you're using `"rgxx"` which is just for `","` If I switch it back to `rgx` instead, I get the same error.

Comment: I do understand i am using a simple regex but i was able to get all the values in to the vector.

Comment: Yes, with simple regex its fine, but not the more complicated one. I cut it down to 130 columns, instead of the 207 that are there, and it works fine. I'm thinking it could be an implementation of regex issue.

Comment: @ChrisM i have verified with the string you mentioned in the post, if it is not working with other larger strings, i am sorry  couldn't help you. Could me with regex too, large strings and complex regex's can't expect any less.

Comment: I played around with the string I was attempting to match, using different numbers of columns (commas). 153 matches works, 154 fails.

Comment: @ChrisM Not a clue, better stop and move on. Some times it is best thing to do.